# How to implement Spring Boot Starting/Restarting page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When I'm starting my Spring Boot application it takes time to load all needed artifacts which is totally acceptable. It takes 2 minutes for the user to wait.

Is it possible to implement starting page "**Hello! We are starting... Just wait a moment**" and reload it to main page when it's done? I'm using Spring Boot.

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment but would be a great feature to have.

Comment: From the top of my head.... if you would use bootstrap context than maybe it could be enhanced in a way you need it. Try to ask a question directly as a GitHub issue-question on Spring Web project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [this solution](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/09/displaying-progress-of-spring.html).

Tomcat is started when all Beans are initilizazed, so you can monitor this initilization and display on some page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could put HTTP server proxying your server. In case your server is down you could display a simple HTML page with the message your proposed.

```
ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

ErrorDocument 404 /loading.html
```

In this page perform AJAX call to your real page. For example (for convenience I used jQuery, but you could also use vanilla javascript or another library):

```
function pollPage(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/realpage", function(data) { //when page is loaded, replace content of current page
        var replacePage = document.open("text/html", "replace");
        replacePage.write(data);
        replacePage.close();
    }, function(){
         setTimeout(pollPage, 10000); //If page is still inaccesible try again in 10 seconds
    });
}
```

This would replace the whole initial page with your real page.